# db2 show a message if data is inserted in table

Tags: db2

I have this procedure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_COUNTRY(IN P_NAME VARCHAR(50))
SPECIFIC INSERT_COUNTRY
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
INSERT INTO "BUILDING MANAGEMENT".COUNTRY (COU_NAME) VALUES (P_NAME);
END
```

How can I put a condition which will print a message defined by me if the data was inserted in table or not.

Comment: Do you mean "print a message" for error handling? If there is an error, the procedure will return it. There is also the `SIGNAL` statement for user-defined error messages.

Comment: Which type of platform is your DB2 server running on? IBM i, Linux-Unix-Windows, or z/OS?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you cannot print anything from a routine, because it runs deep in the bowels of database server, from where there is no output. However, DB2 for LUW v. 9.7 and later have this built-in module, `DBMS_OUTPUT`, which lets you print messages *only* if you run your code in the DB2 command-line processor.

A more general method might be to create a temporary table, insert your message into it, and return a cursor over that table from your stored procedure.

Comment: Than you very much! I had figure it out how should I do.